# Changing ISO setting in Google Glass

Tags: camera, google-glass

I am trying to change the ISO setting in the camera of the Google Glass by using the camera API according to

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = cameraObject.getParameters();
String isoStr = parameters.get("iso"); 
int target = 800;
parameters.set("iso", target);
cameraObject.setParameters(parameters);
```

However, this changes nothing in my app. Is this not supported for the Google Glass? Is there some workaround?

Note:

- I have checked that my starting ISO value is 100
- The allowed values are:

  ```
  iso-mode-values=auto,100,200,400,800
  ```
- I have tried this on two android phones and it's working.

Comment: Take a look at your logcat when applying the `cameraObject.setParameters()`. You can also use the `flatten()` method before and after the `setParameters()` call to see if the setting is applyed or not.

Comment: That is how I got the allowed values for the ISO. Actually, the "iso" is overwritten in the parameters after setParameters() but this is not mirrored in the device. That is why I don't think this is supported.